# Output Knockout observable value even if false

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using a Knockout observable called `this.expanded` to both handle whether or not to render some HTML, and also using the value inside an `aria-expanded` attribute.

```
<button data-bind="attr: { 'aria-expanded': expanded }">
<!-- ko if : expanded -->
   <div>...</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The problem with using my variable `expanded` in both cases is that I notice when `expanded` is false, I don't get the output of `aria-expanded` attribute at all.

```
// When expanded is true:
<button aria-expanded="true"></button>

// When expanded is false:
<button></button>

// What I want:
<button aria-expanded="false"></button>
```

How can I still output the attribute, just with `false`, when `expanded` is false?

I tried creating a secondary variable which would check the observable and convert it to a string:

```
this.expandedStatus = this.expanded().toString()
```

But I noticed that `expandedStatus` does not seem to update/observe anymore if used in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a really simple solution, which was just to set the aria-expanded via a ternary:

```
<button data-bind="attr: { 'aria-expanded': expanded() ? 'true' : 'false' }">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply bind the `aria-expanded` attribute to the `toString()` value of the observable without introducing a new observable. Have a look at the example below:

```js
function Test() {
  var self = this;
  self.expanded = ko.observable(false);
  self.toggleExpanded = function() {
    self.expanded(!self.expanded());
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Test());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="attr: { 'aria-expanded': expanded().toString() }">
<!-- ko if : expanded -->
   <span>...</span>
<!-- /ko -->
</button>

<p>
  <button data-bind="click: toggleExpanded">Toggle</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I ended up finding a really simple way to do this without additional functions (just posted the answer).

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to use binding handler along with jQuery for more convenience like this:

```
<button data-bind="isAriaExpanded: expanded ">
<!-- ko if : expanded -->
   <div>...</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.isAriaExpanded= {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        jQuery(element).attr('aria-expanded',false);//initially setting to false
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      value = valueAccessor();
      valueUnwrapped = ko.unWrap(value);
      jQuery(element).attr('aria-expanded',valueUnwrapped);//whenever the expanded() is changed automatically aria-expanded attribute gets updated
    }
};
```